# How to use System.out.format(); so that the answer can look like that?

Tags: java

```
 String[] B= {"2","14","5","12","10"};
 String[] I= {"20","25","18","16","22"};
 String[] N= {"42","32","FREE","31","39"};
 String[] G= {"60","55","53","46","59"};
 String[] O= {"64","70","67","75","71"};

 System.out.format();
}

}
```

Expected answer :

```
B         I             N            G            O 
2         20            42           60           64
14        25            32           55           70
5         18            FREE         53           67
12        16            31           46           75
10        22            39           59           71
```

Comment: Post some working code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please show us [what you have tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) so far?

Comment: Hand-crafting a loop won't be so difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get your expected out put using this code

```
    String[] B = {"2", "14", "5", "12", "10"};
    String[] I = {"20", "25", "18", "16", "22"};
    String[] N = {"42", "32", "FREE", "31", "39"};
    String[] G = {"60", "55", "53", "46", "59"};
    String[] O = {"64", "70", "67", "75", "71"};

    String[][] test={B,I,N,G,O};
    int n=0;
    System.out.println("B  I  N  G  O");
    for(String[] str:test){
         for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++){
             System.out.print(test[i][n] + " ");
         }
        System.out.println("\n");
        n++;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use `%-<n>s`, where `<n>` is your required "column" length:

```
System.out.printf("'%-8s%-8s'\n", "hello", "world");
```

gives:

```
'hello   world   '
```

Note that more generally, you can use a [`Formatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html). This is what `printf()` uses.